# Jenkins login fails to complete

Tags: security, jenkins, connection, abort

I am working with systems behind a corporate firewall.

Jenkins is installed in a Google cloud server and I initially had external IP of the server, open for access in Google Cloud Firewall rules.

Recently a change request came from the corporate security team, for which I had to block the public/external IP access to Jenkins. The VPN allows me to connect to Jenkins on Internal IP.

Since then I am able to open the Jenkins console-login page...but after I submit the credentials, the login of Jenkins is failing to complete... This is forcing me use RDP to the remote Jenkins server to access the Jenkins console.

The login form gets submitted/redirected to "/j_acegi_security_check" url. This eventually responds as "net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED"

Any pointer would be much appreciated, to fix this issue.

Comment: Dear folks, I am keen to hear any suggestion on this...please do share your thoughts...